# making a generic Modal with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make a generic Modal,so if I click add button I want the modal to open with Add functionality and if I click the edit button, I want the same modal but with edit functionnalities..like change the order

Here is my code

```
<c-row>
        <c-col>
          <button style="float: right;" cButton color="primary" (click)="onAddFamille()">Add Famille</button> //Add button
        </c-col>
      </c-row>
      <c-row>
          <table [striped]="true" cTable>
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Libelle</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let famille of familles">
            <th scope="row">{{famille.id}}</th>
            <td>{{famille.libelle}}</td>
            <td>
              <button cButton color="primary"  (click)="onUpdate(famille.id)">
                <svg cIcon name="cilPen" size="sm" title="Numbered List Icon"></svg>
              </button>
              |
              <button cButton color="danger">
                <svg cIcon name="cilTrash" size="sm" title="Numbered List Icon"></svg>
              </button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

      </c-row>
    </c-card-body>
  </c-card>
</div>
//Modal

<c-modal id="liveDemoModal" [visible]="visible" (visibleChange)="handleLiveDemoChange($event)">
<c-modal-header>
<h2 cModalTitle>Modal title</h2>
<button (click)="toggleLiveDemo()" cButtonClose></button>
</c-modal-header>
<c-modal-body>
  <label cLabel for="exampleFormControlInput1">Libelle</label>
  <c-input-group class="flex-nowrap">
    <input
       aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
       aria-label="Libelle"
       cFormControl
       placeholder="Libelle"
       id="libelle"
       sizing="lg"
       [(ngModel)] = "famille.libelle"
       name="libelle"
      />
    </c-input-group>
</c-modal-body>
<c-modal-footer>
<button (click)="toggleLiveDemo()" cButton color="secondary">
Close
</button>
<button cButton color="primary" (click)="updateFamille()">Save changes</button>
</c-modal-footer>
</c-modal>
```

and here is my Ts code

```
onUpdate(famille:any){
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    this.familleService.getFamille(famille)
    .subscribe(
      (successResponse) =>{
        this.famille =  successResponse;
      },
      (errorResponse) =>{
        console.log(errorResponse)
      }
    )

  }

onAddFamille( ){
    this.visible = !this.visible;

  }
```

the update is working very well but if I click edit button and then click the add button the form comes with th name of the last clicked edit input

Comment: Can you specify a littler bit better in which part of your code the error occurs and what exactly the issue is? What do you mean bei "clicked edit input". Maybe you can add comments in your code where some value is not as expected.

Comment: I have one Modal and I want it to open if I click Add button or Edit button.here if I click Edit and the Add,the Add modal open with Edit functionnalities ,it's not coming as empty

Answer (score 0):

You should call `delete this.famille` in the `onAddFamille` function, otherwise the previously stored famille is still set. Or in your case it would be suitable to set an object containing the needed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Set null to famille variable on add click

```
  onAddFamille( ){
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    this.famille = null; // or this.famille = undefined;
  }
```

Also, check null in input value binding

```
     <input
       aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
       aria-label="Libelle"
       cFormControl
       placeholder="Libelle"
       id="libelle"
       sizing="lg"
       [(ngModel)] = "famille?.libelle"
       name="libelle"
      />
      <!--Note ? in famille?.libelle-->
```